# Firefox.... Bookmark shenanigans

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Firefox has been upgraded. I am now using 57.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. To be honest, I did not even know I have upgraded. Oh well, looks nice.

But, ALL my bookmarks, every single one of them, has vanished. Gone. Ido. Borte. Không còn. Mennyt......

Does anybody know where, in Ubuntu, FF keeps it's book marks so I can have a root around and see if the previous ones are there somewhere... ?

Comment: Three lines menu -- Customize -- pick the bookmarks button (looks like an underlined star) and drag it to a place on the address bar. Why they chose not to display it by default is a mystery.

Comment: @mikewhatever or `~/.mozilla/firefox/profile_name/bookmarkbackups`

Comment: There's a new icon for me with FF57 added to my toolbar on the far-right, it looks like a book and I assumed it was the "reader" button but it's called "sidebars" and opening it shows a unified sidebar for history/bookmarks/etc.. Is everything else working? Initially I thought I'd lost all bookmarks but I think it was related to my font problems.